# Not able to use resources inside .cs file

Tags: asp.net, resources

I have project asp.net with namespace test and I'm using resources (files Resource.resx and Resource.en-GB.resx). I have in resources key MY_TEXT with value. In file .aspx I can use

```
<%# Resources.Resource.MY_TEXT %>
```

but when I'm using (like in article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx)

```
myLabel.Text = Resource.MYTEXT;
```

It don't found it and I have build error. Why?

Best regards,
Dagna

Comment: What is the build error?

Comment: The name 'Resource' don't exist in current context. And it's red underline.

Comment: Now I make myLabel.Text = test.App_GlobalResources.Resource.MYTEXT;, and I have error: 'test.App_GlobalResources.Resource' does not contain a definition for 'MYTEXT'

Comment: In which folder of your project's structure the `Resource` file resides?

Comment: In App_GlobalResources, both version of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
myLabel.Text = Resources.Resource.MYTEXT;
```

Let me know if it works or what kind of error the compiler gives you.

You can also write it as you wrote in your question, click on `Resources` to put cursor there, hit *Ctrl + .* and select a namespace to be added. This should make Visual Studio detect a valid `Resource` namespace (or suggest few available namespaces) automatically.

**Update**

This article explains how to use resources in code behind:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I mentioned it in comments and it helped you, so I'm adding it as a part of an answer.

Comment: I have error: The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. This article seems to suggest it as I wrote it. Please verify if you can resolve `Resources` namespace.

Comment: It don't work in express I think. I used "Resolve" and promt me System.Resources and System.Web.Resources. With both I have error "The type or namespace name 'Resource' does not exist in the namespace 'XXX' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: GetGlobalResourceObject() is working, thank you. Strange that Resources.Resource.MYTEXT does not work, but I'm happy thet is here different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a text from resources using some methods in aspx.cs file.
 For local resources:

```
myLabel.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("MYTEXT").ToString();
```

For global resources:

```
myLabel.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("MYTEXT").ToString();
```

For more information visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.140%29.aspx